# Sylow-2 subgroup of Group of order 56

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $G$ is a group of order $56$ and has a non-normal Sylow-7 subgroup. I know that in this case $G$ contains a normal Sylow-2 subgroup $Q$. I need to show that $Q \cong (\mathbb{Z}_{2})^3$. A hint was given that we can consider a $g \in G : |g|=7$ and the action of $g$ on $Q$. I know that if all the orders of the non-identity elements in $Q$ have order $2$ then $Q \cong (\mathbb{Z}_{2})^3$, but I don't know the argument to get there.

Comment: See the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261241/let-g-be-a-group-of-order-56-then-which-of-the-following-are-true) by Alexander Gruber: "Assume that ...thus $Q\cong \mathbb{Z_2}\times \mathbb{Z_2} \times \mathbb{Z_2}$."